# The player plays the same channel with the same url, but with different ports

Tags: android, port, android-mediaplayer

The player cannot play streams from one URL, but from different ports, it always shows the same channel.

*Url, for example:*

https: // url: 5050 / channel-id / index.m3u8,

https: // url: 5253 / channel-id / index.m3u8,

https: // url: 5583 / channel-id / index.m3u8

This is only on smartphones and tablets.

Players on stb, smart tv and pc work properly and show different channels from different ports.

**Media** **player**, **ijk**, **vlc** - show the same channel.

**Exo** - shows nothing

Can I fix this somehow or is it a feature of smartphones and tablets?

If possible, tell me how to do this?